# Подключение стилей style против link

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброе время суток. Есть достаточно важный вопрос. Я разрабатываю программное обеспечение на nodejs. Это некого рода фреймворк на чистом pure JS. Размеры фреймворка стали огромными, а архитектура SCSS получила гигантский масштаб. Вот только есть одна сложность. В конфигурации фреймворка можно кастомизировать различные элементы, конкретно - устанавливая им цвета. И получается, что подгружается через link большой css файл, а потом в заголовке вставляется тэг style с кастомными настройками. В какой-то момент мне стало проще генерировать таблицу стилей через JS, учитывая что я написал целый набор инструментов для создания css блока.

Вопрос в чем: могу ли я отказаться от link тэга и писать все в index.html ? Очень важен момент оптимизации и времени загрузки приложения.

Comment: Ну так возьми и замерь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из основных преимуществ подключения файла стилей через link заключается в том, что браузер будет кешировать загружаемые таким образом css файлы. Соответственно, если файл большой, как в вашем случае, то более предпочтительным будет использовать именно такой способ.